# Chrome Native Native Messaging Api: How to open native applictaion(.exe) per tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

Hi I am converting my NPAPI plugin to native Messaging app.
I have gone through `http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/` 
In this example native app(.exe) is launched per tab.
But in my case it is launched only once for chrome.
Here is the my manifest.json.

```
{
   "background": {
      "page": "background.html"
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "contentscript.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
   } ],
   "description": "Native Messaging api",
   "key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAO",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Test Extension",
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "nativeMessaging" ],

}
```

here is the background.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
   </head>
  <body>
     <script src="background_pg_helper.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can launch my native application only inside "background_pg_helper.js" by calling

```
var hostName = "com.google.chrome.example.echo";
port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
```

Which is a single instance.

I want to launch my native application as per tab so that one .exe can manage one tab. 
how should i do this?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to create a persistent port per tab (you could use single, one-time messaging, but that is not persistent). Why not modify your .exe so that it handles the separation interarnally (e.g. recognize each tab by the port Id or have the tabs sends their IDs along with any request (there are other approaches possible as well)) ?

Comment: @Nik: please share some informations why its not running at all? http://stackoverflow.com/q/26021106/285594